# Programmatically creating a type from an object's defined fields

Tags: typescript

```
type Supertype = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: string,
  d: string
}

const subtypeObject: Partial<Supertype> = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
}

// goal is to define a type that is
// type: Subtype = {
//   c: string,
//   d: string
// }
```

without having to specify the fields, so no Pick<Supertype, 'c' | 'd>

typeof subtypeObject still has 'a' and 'b' fields

Comment: If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `subtypeObject` as `Partial<Supertype>` then all is lost; you can't retrieve information you've thrown away.  You probably want to use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WG2xXm). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write an answer (after searching for an appropriate duplicate); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)?

Comment: @jcalz satisfies is just what I was looking for, thank you!. it seems quite new so I didn't know about it

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you want to keep only the properties `c` and `d` or to remove the properties `a` and `b` of type `Supertype`, one of the TypeScript utility types [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) or [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) can answer the question:

```js
type Supertype = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: string,
  d: string
}

type KeepCandD = Pick<Supertype, 'c' | 'd'>
type OmitAandB = Omit<Supertype, 'a' | 'b'>


const object1: KeepCandD = {
    a: 'a',        // Error: 'a' does not exist in type 'KeepCandD'
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd'
};

const object2: OmitAandB = {
    b: 'b',        // Error: 'b' does not exist in type 'OmitAandB'
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd'
};
```

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=3#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygV2gJ3NGBeGBvYN8wCGAXDAM4jICWAdgOYA0eBARqRdfUwTAMbuVajZvgAmAznWABfYKEiwA0lCgQAwoRqiAIphgAFKrwDWAHkQo0UBjADkvWzAA+d0bYB889AHkAtlRAAQU1RACE9PwDzJChUBRtbQkcXWxYPOV4AexoKGEyWACsoXhAARlJlVQ0tXSxcHhI7JO4CfjsHFrFSWzcZAG4M7Nz8opKAJlJIoJDwupEYNjs0zr5ujvnxV1t+oA).

Answer (score 0):

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of a variable (with a non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type), then that type is the only thing the compiler will remember about the variable. It will not keep track of any more specific type of any value you assign to it:

```
const subtypeObject: Partial<Supertype> = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
}
// const subtypeObject: Partial<Supertype>
```

This allows you to modify the variable in ways consistent with the annotated type without issue:

```
subtypeObject.b = "b";
delete subtypeObject.c;
subtypeObject; // const subtypeObject: Partial<Supertype>
```

But that flexibility means the compiler is not trying to figure out anything more specific about the variable.  So [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) will only see the annotated type.  You've thrown away the information you care about.

---

Instead, you should just let the compiler infer the type of your variable:

```
const subtypeObject = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
};
/* const subtypeObject: {
    c: string;
    d: string;
} */
```

And from this you could calculate your `Subtype` type:

```
type Subtype = typeof subtypeObject;
/* type Subtype = {
    c: string;
    d: string;
} */
```

---

Now you might object that nothing is actually constraining `subtypeObject` to `Partial<Supertype>`, and you'd be right about that:

```
const subtypeObject = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 3 // <-- no error
};
/* const subtypeObject: {
    c: string;
    d: number;
} */
```

If you care about the compiler checking that the value is assignable to `Partial<Supertype>` without throwing away more specific information about it, then you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to get this behavior:

```
const subtypeObject = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 3 // <-- error!
} satisfies Partial<Supertype>;
```

And that will catch mistakes so you can fix them:

```
const subtypeObject = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
} satisfies Partial<Supertype>

/* const subtypeObject: {
    c: string;
    d: string;
} */

type Subtype = typeof subtypeObject;
/* type Subtype = {
    c: string;
    d: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)